# Custom `rsync` command to sync my Documents and Dropbox?

Tags: dropbox, rsync

This is what I want to achieve:

Dropbox Directory Structure:

- Dropbox/

  - 1passwordstuff
  - Music
  - documentfolder1
  - documentfolder2

Documents Structure:

- Documents/

  - documentfolder1
  - documentfolder2

Then, I want to do all of my work within the Documents folder. So let's say I make some changes to a file in documentfolder1, then I want to call a command like `rsync ...` and have all of my changes pushed into Dropbox. I've managed to achieve this with `rsync -r --ignore-existing Documents Dropbox` but there's a problem. Let's say I delete some files in Documents/documentfolder1/somefile then I want those files in my Dropbox folder to also get deleted. I don't know how to do this.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Voted to close, since this question isn't programming-related, but I think you want `rsync --delete`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use the symbolic links?

Create a symbolic link in the dropbox folder to the Documents folder, and everything will get synced, and you still will work in your Documents location.

just go to your dropbox folder and run

```
ln -s PATH_TO_DOCUMENTS Documents
```